# Error "timeout.close is not a function" when try to clear interval - angular(5)

Tags: angular

I get this error when i do clear interval:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: timeout.close is not a function
TypeError: timeout.close is not a function
    at exports.clearTimeout.exports.clearInterval (main.js:14)
    at LiveTestGraphComponent.ngOnDestroy
```

The set interval function:

```
this.inrvl = setInterval(() => loop(+new Date()), 5);
```

And the destroy function:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.inrvl) clearInterval(this.inrvl)
}
```

The component destroy with ngIf in parent component:

```
<test *ngIf="data.length" </test>
```

Comment: if you are imported this ```import { clearTimeout } from "timers"; ``` please remove then check it will work for me.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

It's because of your IDE! Make sure your IDE didn't include automatic imports such as

```
import { clearInterval } from 'timers';
```

If so, remove them. Rest should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem with `clearTimeout`.

using `window.clearTimeout` instead of `clearTimeout` works too in case you need the `import { clearTimeout } from "timers";` or `import { clearInterval } from 'timers';` imports.