# e.close is not a function in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

have this code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const redirectedFromRegister =
      sessionStorage.getItem("redirectedFlag") === "yes";
    if (!redirectedFromRegister) redirect("/");
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const changeRouteTimeout: NodeJS.Timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      sessionStorage.removeItem("redirectedFlag");
      redirect("/trainees");
    }, 7500);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(changeRouteTimeout);
    };
  }, []);
```

and get this error:

> Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: e.close is not a function
>
> Call Stack t.clearTimeout.t.clearInterval

Comment: It seems there is issue with close method but without whole context it is very difficult to address the issue.Could you please add some more code?

Comment: Did you look at: [Error "timeout.close is not a function" when try to clear interval - angular(5)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48046983)

Comment: There is no more code because the rest of the component is just returning HTML, also when deleting the useEffects the issue is gone. its defenitely with the second useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

chatGPT fixed the error, but im not sure if thats the correct way

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let isUnmounted = false;

    const changeRouteTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      if (!isUnmounted) {
        sessionStorage.removeItem("redirectedFlag");
        redirect("/trainees");
      }
    }, 7500);

    return () => {
      isUnmounted = true;
    };
  }, []);
```